# Drivers lost after reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, printing

My Ubuntu (18.04) has lost the connection to its drivers (namely NVIDIA 450.57 and CUDA/cuDNN, and printer) after rebooting. I have installed the NVIDIA and CUDA drivers using .run files downloaded from the NVIDIA homepage.

Since the reboot, the screen resolution has been reset to the state without the drivers, and `nvidia-smi` returns `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch` . Attempts to print documents returns a 'plain error' message.

I have read that this could be caused by updating my kernel, which I don't recall having done, and in most of the cases a reboot would help (which it didn't).

I was wondering **if** my kernel has been updated and if so, if there is a way to connect the drivers to the new kernel.

Reinstallation of the drivers have helped to fix the issue, yet not 'by it's cause'

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. I have managed to fix it in a very simple way. Going to **Software and Updates > More drivers**, you can **select the driver you previously installed**, in my case NVIDIA driver metapackage from *nvidia-driver-460 (privative, tested)*.

see screenshot (spanish version)
[image]
It seems that Ubuntu can change your default graphics card driver.